# Translationkeys VTiger

Tags: key, translation, vtiger, vtigercrm

Right now im working on VTigers translations.

My friend wants to install the CRM on his Webspace and he needs his translation (in this case - german).

So far i created the most translation keys. 
The most are links are fine.

But in the header menu up to the right side i only can see the translation keys as far they are not linked properly.

I hope you can see what i mean.

Please have a look here -> https://prnt.sc/sokyob

I cant see why this "Keys" dont have get linked like: LBL_SETTING => "Settings", LBL_ADD_RECORDS => "Add Record".

Kind regards
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

you have to add it manualy in languages/de_de/{YourModule}.php
Like :

```
$languageStrings = array(
...
'LBL_EDIT_FIELDS' => '%s Fields & Layout',
'LBL_EDIT_WORKFLOWS' => '%s Workflows',
'LBL_EDIT_PICKLIST_VALUES' => 'Picklists Values',
'LBL_MODULE_SEQUENCE_NUMBERING' => '%s Numbering',
...
);
```